# Javascript values in android

Tags: android, webview, httpclient

I need to get a Value in script(Javascript) and need to display in my TextView

Code in my script, and i had launched it in my apache tomcat server

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function multiply(){
a=Number(document.calculator.number1.value);
b=Number(document.calculator.number2.value);
c=a*b;
document.calculator.total.value=c;
}
</script>
```

Code in my Class file:

```
Webfn.setText(a);
```

I need to get values from online and i need to send it back to the server after calculating.

Comment: Are you going to be building the website?

Comment: No. I have a native application (simple calculator). Now i m makin it hybrid. I need to get values from some online web consider this one as example http://waffle.codehaus.org/images/examples/simple-calculator.png I need to value form the javascript and need to use it in my android app and post it back to server